# JMeter message throughput too low

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I am trying to use JMeter to test an ActiveMQ cluster. As per requirements, I need to get at least 2k messages per second as a test. The issue is that I can't get to the required number of messages.

I am trying to test it against a local queue before going into the cluster, and the results are not good. In a PC (quite beefy) with Windows 10 installed, the best I can do is a few hundred messages per second. In a Mac (Macbook Pro) with OSX 10, I can pump it up to around 1.5k.

I have tried different configurations in JMeter: varying the number of threads, size of messages, Request&Response mode vs Request only... But nothing does the trick.

When I run custom code, I can push around 10k messages into the queue in a second. Are there any particular configurations that I might be missing? I have been through the tutorials online, but I can't find anything that fixes the issue.

Comment: do you get any JMeter exception (e.g. out of memory)? if not, are you hitting any OS limitations? I would start from port usage which could be an easy bottleneck. Or is it simply slower than you expected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer after fiddling with it for hours. Turns out there is a checkbox that is unticked by default which makes all messages persistent. When I ticked it, I got the throughput that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter default configuration is good for tests development and debugging, but when it comes to conducting the high load you need to remember several important points:

1. Don't use GUI for tests execution, you are supposed to be running tests using [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Default JVM Heap allocation is 512 Mb only, you will definitely need to raise this setting in JMeter startup script. Same applies to stack size and garbage collector settings. See [JVM Tuning: Heapsize, Stacksize and Garbage Collection Fundamental](http://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/) article to learn more about JVM internals.
3. Don't use [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during the load test, they cause huge overhead in terms of resources utilization and don't add any value.
4. Reduce usage of [Pre](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to the absolute minimum.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for above points explained and few more tips.

As a last resort in case you hit the hardware limits of a single load generator machine you can always consider [running JMeter in distributed mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) and add more JMeter engines.